# Mixed model - maximum number of groups?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model, modeling

I am trying to fit a mixed model to determine the effect of `X` on `Y` after controlling for non-independence in my data. Non-independence arises from a variable: `ProductID`. I have close to 10,000 observations in my dataset and 5500 unique `ProductID`. Is the average number of observations per `ProductID` being too less ( < 2) a conceptual problem for fitting the below mixed model in R?

```
lmer(Y~ X + (1|ProductID), myData)
```

If it is a conceptual problem, should I be looking at some other grouping variable - such as `ProductCategoryID` (100 unique ones) - in place of `ProductID` to account for non-independence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lmer` should have no problem fitting a model with an average of 1.8 observations per cluster. In general, problems arise where there are too few groups, not too many. The [minimum sample size per cluster is 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388937/minimum-sample-size-per-cluster-in-a-random-effect-model/389095#389095).  Changing the grouping level as you suggest will lead to a loss of information and should be avoided if possible. Instead, it may make sense to specify nested random effects, if there is variation at the `ProductCategoryID` level:

```
lmer(Y~ X + (1|ProductCategoryID/ProductID), myData)
```