# How does data sparisty affect the predictive abilities of mixed linear models?

Tags: mixed-model

I am new to statistical modelling and I have a potentially silly question. I've been working with a mixed model where the design matrix of one of the categorical random predictors (`r_id`) is sparse: i.e. typically each level of the predictor is only associated with a couple of data points.

My model equation is:

```
model_set1 <- asreml(fixed = mean_score ~ 1 + sh_count + yob + sex, random = ~ vm(an_id, ainv) + idv(r_id), residual = ~ idv(units), data = df)
```

The number of observations in `mean_score` is 896. The number of levels in `r_id` is 664. Some `r_id`'s have multiple `mean_score`s (range 1 to 7, mean 1.36) and some `mean_score`s have multiple `r_id`s (range 1 to 5, mean 1.32).

I was somewhat surprised when the variance estimate for this was quite large (32% of `mean_score`'s variance). Is this likely to be because my model is overfit to the data? Intuitively I feel that this variable is not very informative because we don't have very much data on which to estimate the effect of a single level of the predictor, but perhaps my intuition is wrong.

I am interested to know if those experienced running linear mixed models would even chose to include such a predictor in their model. I am interested in more getting an intuition for this issue (pointers to textbooks/other resources welcome!), that will extend beyond this one example.

(Perhaps 'sparse' is not the best way to describe this and thus this is why I struggled to find an answer elsewhere, and if not, please correct me).

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's a bit hard to answer without more info. What is the overall size of the dataset ? How many levels does the variable in question have in total ? Is this variable a grouping factor that you are fitting random intercepts for ? What other variables are in the model ? What is the model formula ? Please include the model output. If working in R please also post the output of `str(mydata)`. It sounds like you have small cluster sizes but that is not necessarily a problem nor should it have anything to do with the variance estimate (why do you think it is quite large ?

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you for your feedback. I have updated my question a bit, but your description of my problem in terms of cluster size was actually probably help enough - when I look this up using that terminology I get the answers I'm looking for. For example, I think my question is answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388937/minimum-sample-size-per-cluster-in-a-random-effect-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to say whether for `id` to account for 32% of the variation in your outcome is too high. In general unless you simulated the data or you know *a priori* for some other reason (for example previous studies or other domain knowledge) what the expected variance is, you can't really know what to expect.

Certainly it seems that you have a lot of singleton clusters but the accepted answer to [the linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388937/minimum-sample-size-per-cluster-in-a-random-effect-model) you mentioned in the question comments says that the minimum cluster size is 1 with a few caveats. You could try to adapt the code there to give insight into your particular situation.

One other note:

> I was somewhat surprised when the variance estimate for this was quite large (32% of `mean_score`'s variance)

A better comparison is to compare the variance to the residual variance (plus any other variance components), not to the variance of the outcome.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I think I worded that wrong, I calculated 32% as the variance explained by `r_id` over the sum of the residual variance and the variance explained by both random effects (`r_id` and `an_id`). I will definitely have a go at working through the example in the linked question.