# Mixed effects models - clusters with one observation

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm quite new with GLMM, and I'm fitting a linear mixed model in R since I'm dealing with longitudinal data. I want to treat subjects id as random effect.

I have 290 clusters made up by subjects observed from one to 14 times, and a relative large number (45) are observed only once, should I drop them ? I'd not since they are many. Is that still okay having many subjects observed once?

Comment: Welcome to CV Maximilian. Unfortunately, I am recommending closure for your question: The way CV works, you have the basis of three separate questions here (1 from each paragraph). I would recommend editing your question ("edit" link at lower left) to remove the second two questions, and ask those as two separate new questions.

Comment: Question amended. Could you pls unlock the question?

Comment: Done! :D Also look around the site, I know there have been similar questions.

Comment: [Minimum sample size per cluster in a random effect model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/388937/237901)

Comment: Thanks so much, I think that the question already answered and just flagged in the last comment is quite exhaustive.